# Forwarding domains on NGINX with and w/o www

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, dns

I have a personal website, which runs on Ubuntu 17.10 with NGINX to serve a static site and enabled LetsEncrypt. I have the following problem:

```
testdomain.com -> 404
http://testdomain.com -> 404
https://testdomain.com  -> works
www.testdomain.com  -> works
https://www.testdomain.com -> works
```

I attached the DNS settings and the `nginx.conf` file.

[image: nginx.conf screenshot]

[image: dns screenshot]

Could you point me in the direction?

Comment: Please put settings at text in your question, not as an image.

Comment: Sorry yes, i won't do it in the future, was my first stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you config only listens on port 443, and port 80 with the `www.example.com` hostname.

Try adding something like this in the Vhost configuration:

```
  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;

    #do stuff here    

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, i got it. The working solution is: 
    server {
    listen  80;server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;

        }


Only minor error when reloading the NGINX configuration was "nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored"